# Excel Import Generic Framework

Tags: library, ruby

I am looking for generic framework/gem/library in Ruby/Rails which will do following things:

- read data from excel
- Parse data
- validate each row and fields. Fields can have complex rules
- Error handling
- save data to schema

I searched on Google and found [this C# add-in](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442357/Excel-Add-in-Framework-for-Validating-and-Exportin).

Do we have any such framework in Ruby/Rails?

Comment: Are you building server-based solution?

Answer (score 1):

A library that I've come across which sounds like it will do at least some of what you're after is [RubyXL](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL).  Definitely it'll allow opening/reading/parsing of Excel data.